# Draw a lot of objects with NSBezierPath

Tags: ios, draw, uibezierpath, quartz-core

Hi i need draw many complex objects, like in image [image]

i draw square and point in it with this code:

```
CGFloat mmForSqure = self.frame.size.height/6;
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(originX, originY, mmForSqure, mmForSqure)];
CGFloat originPoint = mmForSqure/4;
for (int i = 1; i<4; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j<4; j++) {
        CGPoint pathPoint = CGPointMake(i*originPoint+originX, j*originPoint+originY);
        [path moveToPoint:pathPoint];
        [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(i*originPoint+originX+1, j*originPoint+originY+1)];
    }
}
CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
shapeLayer.path = path.CGPath;
shapeLayer.fillColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
shapeLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1.0;
[self.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
```

and other squares with two loops

```
CGFloat sizeOfSquared = self.frame.size.height/6;
for (int i = 0; i<=self.frame.size.width/sizeOfSquared; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j!=6; j++) {

    }
}
```

But this is slow UI and take much resources, some one have any idea how optimize resources consumption and UI ??

Comment: why don't you use UICollectionView.. with 9 button in once cell

Answer (score 0):

If u don't need any operations on individual squares, u can try making the lines first(all vertical and 5 horizontal) and then add the dots in a loop using self.frame.size.height/6 divided by 4 as the distance between the points and skip after every 3 points. Just a suggestion. Try it if it works. :)

Comment: what about collectionview thing. is not easy and flexible instead of doing this. what u say

Comment: ya collection view would be a better solution. Thought u needed to use bezier path. Collection view ll make it lot easier. :)